# Read a pixel from ID3D11Resource

Tags: directx-11

I had already rendered a scene to a texture(RTT,render to texture). In this process, the render target is *prtv*[ID3DRenderTargetView*] and the corresponding texture is *ptextureRTV*[ID3D11Resource*].

Now I want to read a pixel from where my mouse is and find something wrong. To figure out where the bug is, I turn to print out the texture to see what it is.

I create a D3D11_USAGE_STAGING resource *ptextureStaging*[ID3D11Resource*] and copy *ptextureRTV* to *ptextureStaging*. Then I map *ptextureStaing*, use its data to create .ppm image and unmap it. However, the image is not the one I want.
[image: .ppm image generated by myself]

I also try to use **SaveDDSTextureToFile** to store the texture into .dds image. It works really well. [image]

here is my code:

**create dds image(pass and correct):**

```
DirectX::SaveDDSTextureToFile(pdx11_unit->pdevCon.Get(), ptextureRTV.Get(), L"Image/image.dds");
```

**copy and map:**

```
RenderToTexture();//prepare texture
pdx11_unit->pdevCon->CopyResource(ptextureStaging.Get(), ptextureRTV.Get());//copy data to staing texutre
D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mappedResource;
ZeroMemory(&mappedResource, sizeof(D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE));
pdx11_unit->pdevCon->Map(ptextureStaging.Get(), 0, D3D11_MAP_READ, 0, &mappedResource);//map to cpu memory
_pixel *pdata = (_pixel*)mappedResource.pData;
//create .ppm image
ofstream image("Image/image.ppm", ios::out | ios::binary | ios::trunc);
image << "P3\n" << Win32Unit::realWidth << " " << Win32Unit::realHeight << "\n255\n";
for (int i = Win32Unit::realHeight - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < Win32Unit::realWidth; j++) {
        int ir = pdata[i*Win32Unit::realWidth + j].r;
        int ig = pdata[i*Win32Unit::realWidth + j].g;
        int ib = pdata[i*Win32Unit::realWidth + j].b;
        image << ir << ' ' << ig << ' ' << ib << '\n';
    }
}
pdx11_unit->pdevCon->Unmap(ptextureStaging.Get(), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the reason. If I have a texture of size 784x561 now and want to read a pixel at (i,j), it is wrong to query ((_pixel*)mappedResource.pdata)[i*784+j] because the mappedResource has width=800 actually. This width equals to mappedResouce.RowPitch/sizeof(_pixel). So, to load pixels into CPU memory, the correct code is:

```
int slicePitch = Win32Unit::realHeight*Win32Unit::realWidth;
int rowCount = Win32Unit::realHeight;
int rowPitch = Win32Unit::realWidth;

std::unique_ptr<_pixel[]> pixels(new (std::nothrow) _pixel[slicePitch]);
_pixel* dptr = pixels.get();
_pixel* sptr = (_pixel*)mappedResource.pData;
for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
    memcpy_s(dptr, rowPitch * sizeof(_pixel), sptr, rowPitch * sizeof(_pixel));
    dptr += rowPitch;
    sptr += mappedResource.RowPitch / sizeof(_pixel);
}
```